# Why Magento2 not loading css and js files in local setup?

Tags: magento2, javascript, htaccess, localhost

my root folder **.htaccess** file

```
RewriteOptions inherit
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php71” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php71 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
############################################
## overrides deployment configuration mode value
## use command bin/magento deploy:mode:set to switch modes

#   SetEnv MAGE_MODE developer

############################################
## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

#    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
#    AddHandler php5-cgi .php

############################################
## GoDaddy specific options

#   Options -MultiViews

## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

############################################
## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting

    #AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
    #AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

############################################
## default index file

    DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
############################################
## adjust memory limit

    php_value memory_limit 756M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000

############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized

    php_flag session.auto_start off

############################################
## enable resulting html compression

    #php_flag zlib.output_compression on

###########################################
## disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php7.c>
############################################
## adjust memory limit

    php_value memory_limit 3G
    php_value max_execution_time 18000

############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized

    php_flag session.auto_start off

############################################
## enable resulting html compression

    #php_flag zlib.output_compression on

###########################################
## disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_security.c>
###########################################
## disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

    # Insert filter on all content
    ###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Insert filter on selected content types only
    #AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json image/svg+xml

    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    #BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # Don't compress images
    #SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    #Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

############################################
## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

    SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

############################################
## workaround for Apache 2.4.6 CentOS build when working via ProxyPassMatch with HHVM (or any other)
## Please, set it on virtual host configuration level

SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
############################################

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    #RewriteBase /equpo/

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks



############################################
## redirect for mobile user agents

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>

############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

    AddDefaultCharset Off
    #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
    AddType 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' html

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/html A0
    ExpiresByType text/plain A0

</IfModule>

###########################################
## Deny access to root files to hide sensitive application information
    RedirectMatch 403 /\.git

<Files composer.json>
    Require all denied
</Files>
<Files composer.lock>
    Require all denied
</Files>
<Files .gitignore>
    Require all denied
</Files>
<Files .htaccess>
    Require all denied
</Files>
<Files .htaccess.sample>
    Require all denied
</Files>
<Files .php_cs.dist>
    Require all denied
</Files>
<Files .travis.yml>
    Require all denied
</Files>
<Files CHANGELOG.md>
    Require all denied
</Files>
<Files COPYING.txt>
    Require all denied
</Files>
<Files Gruntfile.js>
    Require all denied
</Files>
<Files LICENSE.txt>
    Require all denied
</Files>
<Files LICENSE_AFL.txt>
    Require all denied
</Files>
<Files nginx.conf.sample>
    Require all denied
</Files>
<Files package.json>
    Require all denied
</Files>
<Files php.ini.sample>
    Require all denied
</Files>
<Files README.md>
    Require all denied
</Files>
<Files auth.json>
    Require all denied
</Files>
<Files magento_umask>
    Require all denied
</Files>

# For 404s and 403s that aren't handled by the application, show plain 404 response
ErrorDocument 404 /pub/errors/404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /pub/errors/404.php

################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

    #FileETag none

# ######################################################################
# # INTERNET EXPLORER                                                  #
# ######################################################################

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Document modes                                                     |
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Force Internet Explorer 8/9/10 to render pages in the highest mode
# available in the various cases when it may not.
#
# https://hsivonen.fi/doctype/#ie8
#
# (!) Starting with Internet Explorer 11, document modes are deprecated.
# If your business still relies on older web apps and services that were
# designed for older versions of Internet Explorer, you might want to
# consider enabling `Enterprise Mode` throughout your company.
#
# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg182625.aspx#docmode
# http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2014/04/02/stay-up-to-date-with-enterprise-mode-for-internet-explorer-11.aspx

<IfModule mod_headers.c>

    Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=edge"

    # `mod_headers` cannot match based on the content-type, however,
    # the `X-UA-Compatible` response header should be send only for
    # HTML documents and not for the other resources.

    <FilesMatch "\.(appcache|atom|bbaw|bmp|crx|css|cur|eot|f4[abpv]|flv|geojson|gif|htc|ico|jpe?g|js|json(ld)?|m4[av]|manifest|map|mp4|oex|og[agv]|opus|otf|pdf|png|rdf|rss|safariextz|svgz?|swf|topojson|tt[cf]|txt|vcard|vcf|vtt|webapp|web[mp]|webmanifest|woff2?|xloc|xml|xpi)$">
        Header unset X-UA-Compatible
    </FilesMatch>

</IfModule>
```

**`#RewriteBase /myproject/  // here i changed magento 2 root floder name`**

but it's  not working for css and js loading

```
    Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost/equpo/pub/static/version1550763043/frontend/Solwin/kosmic_child/en_US/js/custom/jquery.flexslider.js”. equpo:50:1
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost/equpo/pub/static/version1550763043/frontend/Solwin/kosmic_child/en_US/js/custom/owl.carousel.js”. equpo:51:1
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost/equpo/pub/static/version1550763043/frontend/Solwin/kosmic_child/en_US/js/custom/custom_js.js”. equpo:52:1
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost/equpo/pub/static/version1550763043/frontend/Solwin/kosmic_child/en_US/Solwin_ScrolltoTop/js/scroll.js”. equpo:53:1
TypeError: require.config is not a function[Learn More]
```

how to solve this????

Comment: redeploy your site with the particular language code & theme-name it will load the files & also make sure the directory permission for the `pub/static` directory & its child directories

Comment: run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

Comment: it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Load the URL in browser without any version

`http://localhost/equpo/pub/static/frontend/Solwin/kosmic_child/en_US/js/custom/jquery.flexslider.js`

If it is works.

**For the quick fix**

You can disable the static version from admin or directly changed in Mysql database core_config_data table.

From admin:

Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> Static File Settings

From Mysql:

```
insert into core_config_data (config_id, scope, scope_id, path, value) values (null, 'default', 0, 'dev/static/sign', 0);
```

Note: Enable static version is always recommended so don't disable the static content versioning in production.

**Permanent fix**

You need to find the reason why the versioning URL is not accepted, check the below points and make sure evrything configured correctly

1. Check the file pub/static/.htaccess presents or not, if not, you need recreate it from another installation.
2. Make sure apache “rewrite_module” is enabled
3. Check apache2 config file and it should have `AllowOverride All` properties.

Comment: which file - Make sure apache “rewrite_module” is enabled

i can change

Comment: just run the command it will enable rewrite module. `sudo a2enmod rewrite`

Comment: where the file for 3rd point

Comment: it's presented with htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

try to use this terminal command

```
php bin/magento config:set dev/static/sign 0
```